# rigging tail of a bird : make parent / keep offset expected behaviour of the tutorial is not like mine

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I'm rigging the tail of the bird Piero training course of the CG Cookie and I get stuck on episode 29 : piero rigging spine. The author did `make/parent` and then `keep offset` between a set of bones and the result that he gets is not the same as I get. I don't understand the reasons because I did exactly his own moves. I added two videos :

1) a small piece of tutorial of piero :

[piero tutorial](http://sendvid.com/ewfk43tv)

2) what I did from my side

[what I do](http://sendvid.com/ls9annhw)

3) this should be the correct result :

[correct result](http://sendvid.com/ucq69e03)

4) my result is wrong somewhere :

[image: wrong result]

[image]

Comment: Both links lead to the same video in your question

Comment: fixed. check now.

Comment: added also the blend file...